# How to use a condition to break a tensorflow function?

Tags: tensorflow

I am usinf tf.cond()  to evaluate a boolean during a loop, with the intention to break the loop if the condition is met:

```
        tf.cond(a > b, true_fn=lambda: break, false_fn=lambda : continue)
```

But this syntax does not work.

I also tried this:

```
      if tf.math.greater(a, b):
            break
```

But it also doesnt work, throwing the error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

How can I implement this logic with tensorflow operations?

Comment: How are you doing the loop in the first place? I think that code would be interesting to see.

Comment: That is a good point, I haven't even yet been able to debug the function itself as I am stuck with that conditional statement, but the reason this is not working might be the fact that there is no logical way of writing a for loop in a tf graph, unless if its using the tensorflow function tf.while_loop, which has an in-built termination condition